# How to add multiple text to local Storage HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

I created a few functions and some input boxes with a table to show the data when page is reloaded. The issue I am having is how do I get multiple inserts to local storage and be able to show all the data on the table with a loop statement. Also is there way to show the data right away instead of reload. I guess I am just confused with local Storage and I was trying to see how it works.
https://jsfiddle.net/zzLumrsd/

```
<!DOCTYPE>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title> Local storage</title>
        <style type="text/css">

    table#table1{
        width: 10%; 
        background-color: #gray;
    }

        </style>
        <script>
    function saveMy(){
    var fieldValue = document.getElementById('textfield').value;
    localStorage.setItem('text', fieldValue);
    }

    function load(){

        var storedValue = localStorage.getItem('text');
        if(storedValue){
    document.getElementById('textfield2').value = storedValue;
        }
    }

    function removeMy() {

    document.getElementById('textfield').value = '';
    localStorage.removeItem('text');
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="load()">
    <input type="text" id="textfield" />
    <input type="button" value="save" onclick="saveMy()"/>
    <input type="button" value="remove" onclick="removeMy()"/>
    <hr/>
    <table id="table1" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>text</th>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
    <input type="text" id="textfield2" />

        </td>

      </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: maybe you want something like JSON arrays?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing a list of strings in local storage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18319588/storing-a-list-of-strings-in-local-storage)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to store multiple strings into `localStorage`. You could achieve that using the following:

### How

To achieve this, you would store all the Strings in an array. We can then put this into localStorage. In the examples, I will be using 'names' as the localStorage item name. An array can't be put into localStorage so we have to make it a String using **JSON.stringify** to do that.

### Examples

#### Setting the Item

```
var vals = [];

vals.push('Bob');//Add the text 'item1' to vals

localStorage.setItem('names', JSON.stringify(vals));
```

#### Getting the Item

```
vals = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('name'));
```

In this, we will get the item from localStorage, and make the string into an array again using **JSON.parse**

### Further Explanation

`localStorage` is an **browser API** that allows us to store data on a users computer. `localStorage` is somewhat like *cookies* but are less limited and don't expire.

We want to store in this case, names, in `localStorage`. You can store anything JavaScript in localStorage. Stack Overflow stores timestamps and a few other things in your `localStorage`.

Each `item`, or 'thing' in localStorage, has a **name**, and a **value**.

When using `localStorage.setItem('name', 'Bob')`, you create an `item` called *name* and it's value is *Bob*

This is all well and good until you want to add a second name. JavaScript has **arrays** which can store multiple values in one 'variable'. This means you can store multiple names, in one variable/item. The following is an example of an array

> var myArray = ['Bob', 'Joe', 'Phil'];

That **array** has three values: *Bob*, *Joe*, and *Phil*. You can add an item into an array using `Array.push()`. I'm going to link an article on arrays [**here**](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)

Okay, so now you have your three values in an array and you want to store it. `localStorage` values can **only be strings**! JSON is is a special type of 'variable' similar to a JavaScript object, you can learn about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695883/what-is-json-can-you-explain-it-to-a-newbie). In simple terms, an array is 'JSON'.

Because `localStorage` only takes strings, we must turn our array *(JSON)* into a string which we can store. The way this is done is `JSON.stringify(ARRAY_HERE)`. This will return a string ***like***:

> `"["Bob","Joe","Phil"]"`

Now that our array is a string, we can put it into `localStorage` using `localStorage.setItem()`.

**What do we do when we want to retrieve this?**

To retrieve the array, we will use `localStorage.getItem()`. In `localStorage.getItem()` you put the name of the `item` you wish to access and it will return it. But the problem is it is still a string. That's where `JSON.parse()` comes in. This will convert our 'stringified' array into an actual array.

### What does this all have to do

> I want to store three names in localStorage

How would you do that? It's simple, what you add the names to the array using `.push()`, then you store it. When you want to display it, use the `localStorage.getItem()` I described before.

### Further Reading

I wrote a lot but that might not be enough, check out the following:

[**MDN Arrays**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

[**localStorage Article**](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/)

[**w3schools JSON**](http://www.w3schools.com/json/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74668/discussion-between-donny-and-vihan1086).