# Storage and show multiple outputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple text input where users type anything and after sumbitting text appear on a page and stays there, which I done with localStorage, but after refreshing the page only last typed input is showing, Ill post my code to be more specific:

HTML:

```
<body>
<input id="NewPostField" type="text" value="">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Post</button>
<div id="Posts"></div>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
function myFunction() {
  var NewPostField =
    document.getElementById("NewPostField");
  var newPost = document.createElement("p");

  localStorage.setItem('text',
    NewPostField.value);
  newPost.innerHTML = NewPostField.value;

  var Posts = document.getElementById("Posts");
  Posts.appendChild(newPost);
}

(function() {
  const previousText = localStorage.getItem('text');
  if (previousText) {
    var NewPostField = document.getElementById("NewPostField");
    NewPostField.value = previousText;

    myFunction();
  }
})();
```

Any help will be great!

Comment: It seems that only the last value is stored: `localStorage.setItem('text',NewPostField.value);`

Comment: How do I change that if you can help?

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29497321/9466129) will help you ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add multiple text to local Storage HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29497179/how-to-add-multiple-text-to-local-storage-html5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your code is only storing the last value posted.

To store more than one post, one idea is to [`stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) an array of values to store in `localStorage`.
Then, [`parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) that stringified value back into an array as needed.

Here's an example:

```js
function getExistingPosts() {

  // fetch existing data from localStorage
  var existingPosts = localStorage.getItem('text');

  try {

    // try to parse it
    existingPosts = JSON.parse(existingPosts);

  } catch (e) {}

  // return parsed data or an empty array
  return existingPosts || [];

}

function displayPost(post) {

  // display a post

  var new_post = document.createElement("p");
  new_post.innerHTML = post;
  posts.appendChild(new_post);

}

function displayExistingPosts() {

  // display all existing posts

  var existingPosts = getExistingPosts();

  posts.innerHTML = '';
  inputPost.value = '';

  if (existingPosts.length > 0) {
    existingPosts.forEach(function(v) {
      displayPost(v);
    });
    inputPost.value = existingPosts.slice(-1)[0];
  }

}

function addPost(post) {

  // add a post

  var existing = getExistingPosts();
  existing.push(post);
  localStorage.setItem('text', JSON.stringify(existing));
  displayPost(post);

}

function clearPosts() {

  // clear all posts

  localStorage.removeItem('text');
  displayExistingPosts();

}


var posts = document.getElementById("posts");
var inputPost = document.getElementById("input_post");
var btnPost = document.getElementById('btn_post');
var btnClear = document.getElementById('btn_clear');

btnPost.addEventListener('click', function() {
  addPost(inputPost.value)
});

btnClear.addEventListener('click', clearPosts);

displayExistingPosts();
```

```html
<input id="input_post" type="text" value="">
<button type="button" id="btn_post">Post</button>
<button type="button" id="btn_clear">Clear</button>
<div id="posts"></div>
```

Since `localStorage` [isn't supported in StackSnippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345385/why-are-we-disallowed-to-use-html5-local-storage-on-code-snippets), here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lhwd03k7/1/) to help demonstrate.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thats was what I was looking for.